# Attempting install of 18x or 16x on old Mac Pro results in bizarre glitchy screen

Tags: system-installation, mac, grub-efi

I’ve tried the network, desktop, and server install images for 18.10, 18.04, and 16.04. All of them display the grub menu correctly, but display a flashing screen of random characters when any option is selected, as seen below

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAsFE.jpg]

I’m using a non-EFI graphics card, but as far as I know, that’s only an issue before the boot media is selected.

Machine is Mac Pro 3,1 with 2x5670 and GTX790